# Increasing pthreads thread count has no effect on speed

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

In the following program, increasing the number of threads does not yield any speed-up benefits at all (measured with the time command under linux). I have run on it on the following processors:

- Intel i5 M520
- Intel Xeon X5650

It seems to me that the logic of dividing the work among the threads is correct. I have even tried removing the lock, which obviously gives the wrong result, but still no increase in speed. Any ideas?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double sum;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
typedef struct {
    int start;
    int end;
}sumArg;

void *sumRoots(void *arg) {
    sumArg s = *((sumArg *) arg);
    int i = s.start;
    double tmp;
    while(i <= s.end) {
        tmp = sqrt(i);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        sum += tmp;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        i++;
    }
    free(arg);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int threadCount = atoi(argv[1]);
    int N = atoi(argv[2]);
    if (N < 1 || threadCount < 1) printf("Usage: ./sumOfRoots threads N\n");

    pthread_t tid[threadCount];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    sumArg *s;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < threadCount) {
        s = (sumArg *) malloc(sizeof(sumArg));
        s->start = ((N/threadCount) * i) + 1;
        s->end = (N/threadCount) * (i + 1);
        pthread_create(&tid[i], &attr, sumRoots, s);
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    while(i < threadCount) pthread_join(tid[i++], NULL);
    printf("sum: %f\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:
Here are some runs of the program, all running on an i5 M520:

```
time ./sumOfRoots 1 1000000000
sum: 21081851083600.558594

real    0m21.933s
user    0m21.268s
sys     0m0.000s

time ./sumOfRoots 2 1000000000
sum: 21081851083600.691406

real    0m21.207s
user    0m21.020s
sys     0m0.008s

time ./sumOfRoots 4 1000000000
sum: 21081851083600.863281

real    0m21.488s
user    0m21.116s
sys     0m0.016s

time ./sumOfRoots 8 1000000000
sum: 21081851083601.777344

real    0m21.432s
user    0m21.092s
sys     0m0.020s
```

I believe the variation in the sum is caused by floating point precision loss.

Comment: What arguments do you pass?

Comment: What value are you setting numthreads to?

Comment: what values of `N` and `threadCount` did you try?  Did you try with a very large `N` using different `threadCount`?  If so, can you give those performance numbers?

Comment: However, note that locking on a shared variable inside an inner loop like this will lead to terrible performance.

Comment: I see absolutely no reason to have that mutex latch whatsoever. Calculate a local-sum of the local loop-run, then latch the mutex *once* after the loop to add the local sub to the accumulated `sum` global. As written, you're spending an *incredible* amount of time latching an unlatching a mutex for no real reason except by design choice. And the more threads you throw at it, the more contention on that mutex you're going to introduce.

Comment: It's not just the mutex being contested, it's also the variable `sum` itself (cache line contention).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the timing remains virtually unchanged is that it it dominated by synchronization. On my computer a single-thread solution was even faster!

Changing the code as follows brings the timing in line with expectations:

```
void *sumRoots(void *arg) {
    sumArg s = *((sumArg *) arg);
    int i = s.start;
    double tmp = 0;
    while(i <= s.end) {
        tmp += sqrt(i++);
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    sum += tmp;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    free(arg);
    return 0;
}
```

Now your thread runs for a while without synchronization, and then synchronizes only once during the addition.

The timing I see on my system is as follows:

```
> time ./a.out 1 1000000000
sum: 21081851083600.558594
real    0m13.220s
user    0m13.098s
sys 0m0.009s

> time ./a.out 2 1000000000
sum: 21081851083600.863281

real    0m6.613s
user    0m12.930s
sys 0m0.027s
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing, or even having each thread return a separate sum.  If you sum the thread summary values in "thread creation order" you'll minimize error (since the values being summed within each thread are already monotonically increasing).  (In real code, you'd probably want to do [Kahan summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) or similar.)